# How to handle BitSet type table with the BitSet methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, bitset

I have to create a table with two type BitSet dimensions (9x9).
I fulfills this table with bit values 1 to 9.
I wish to withdraw a value of a particular case (exemple 5), but .set method (int, boolean) modifies all the boxes in my chart.

how to do ??

```
//create
private BitSet[][] solveur = new BitSet[9][9];

//init
BitSet BitInitialisation = new BitSet(); 
BitInitialisation.set(1, 10);

for (int ligne = 0; ligne < 9; ligne++) {
        for (int colonne = 0; colonne < 9; colonne++) {
            solveur[ligne][colonne] = BitInitialisation;
        }
    }

//read + method call 
for (int ligne = 0; ligne < 9; ligne++) {
    for (int colonne = 0; colonne < 9; colonne++) {
            AjusterLigne(ligne ,5);
    }
}

//method "AjusterLigne"

private void AjusterLigne(int ligne, int valeur) {
    for (int colonne = 0; colonne < GrilleSudoku.MAX; colonne++){
        solveur[ligne][colonne].set(valeur, false);
    }   
}
```

result: empty table...

Comment: The loop `colonne` preceding AjusterLigne is useless - it just repeats AjusterLigne 9 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a 9x9 array of `BitSet` references, but set every element value to the same reference - there's only a single `BitSet` object involved. This is just a more complex version of this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder[] array = { builder, builder };
array[0].append("foo");
System.out.println(array[1]); // Prints foo
```

If you really want 81 independent `BitSet` objects, you need to create 81 different `BitSet` objects:

```
for (int ligne = 0; ligne < 9; ligne++) {
    for (int colonne = 0; colonne < 9; colonne++) {
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
        bitSet.set(1, 10);
        solveur[ligne][colonne] = bitSet;
    }
}
```

It's *very* important to understand why this is the case - it's basically a matter of understanding the difference between references and objects in Java, and it's worth spending some time making sure you're clear about it... it affects *everything* you do in Java, pretty much.

Comment: Darn, you're 10 seconds faster anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because Java uses object references.

```
solveur[ligne][colonne] = BitInitialisation;
```

Here you've assigned a reference to `BitInitialisation` in all 81 cells. Modification of any of these will modify the same object. I can propose two solutions:

1. You can create new `BitSet` on every iteration of the inner loop. (That's covered by @JonSkeet answer.)
2. You can call `.clone()` method on the `BitSet` object.

   `solveur[ligne][colonne] = BitInitialisation.clone();`